# Как удалить атрибут на JS Pure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Вот так выгрядит код на jQuery

```
$(".newsBlock").removeAttr("title")
```

Как он будет выглядить на нативном JS? Без библиотек.

Comment: "pure js removeAttr" не пробовали в поисковик вбить??

Answer (score 3):

```js
var newsBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("newsBlock");

 for (var i = 0; i < newsBlock.length; i++) {
   newsBlock[i].removeAttribute("title");
 }
```

```css
.newsBlock {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsBlock" title="block">My block</div>
<div class="newsBlock" title="block">My block</div>
<div class="newsBlock" title="block">My block</div>
<div class="newsBlock" title="block">My block</div>
```

Comment: почему не `removeAttribute`?

Comment: Привычка) Да, removeAttribute будет правильнее

Comment: Ну и циклом ещё если совсем аналогичное поведение надо, тк jquery удалит у всех элементов, а не только у первого.

Comment: Зачем в цикле каждый раз запрашивать `document.getElementsByClassName("newsBlock")`?